# Browser maximum screen size

Tags: browser

I am planning an advertisement display solution that might use a browser with multiple monitors. One of the questions is: is there a limit in the maximum screen size of a browser?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You're generally safe deeming 2,000 pixels or so to be the 99.999%-of-users limit, but there's no hard technological limit preventing some nutter from having a 100,000 pixel browser window displaying on a Times Square-style billboard or something.

Comment: I think I need to go to my IT guy at work and tell him that I demand a 100,000 pixel wide resolution.

Comment: I suspect taking a minute to move the mouse across the screen would be a significant downside. :-) I've seen 10,000+ pixel LDC walls hacked together for things like flight simulators and wall displays, though.

Comment: Exactly, I am thinking if I could be using a browser for something like an LCD wall

Comment: @mico: Maybe in full screen mode.

Comment: yes, a display wall in full screen mode. Html5 seems fine for all animation needs, but I want to be sure I do not hit a wall with technical limitations.
I think I have read in an Opera annoucement I cannot find a limit of 4096x4096 but it sounds strange to me. I expect more trouble from the hardware.

Comment: @mico:  Yep, your video card(s) need to be able to render the pixels quickly.